# Is there any way to enforce uniqueness among items within a XML list using XSD?

Tags: xml, validation, list, xsd

I have an XML file and a corresponding XSD file.
In the XSD file I define a list attribute where the items in the list are part of an enumeration.

Here is an example of what I'm doing.

```
<xs:simpleType name="Colors">
    <xs:list itemType="ColorEnum"/>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="ColorEnum">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
        <xs:enumeration value="Red"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="Blue"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="Green"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:element name="Color">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:attribute name="ColorList" type="Colors" />
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

The XML would look something like this:

```
<Color ColorList="Red Blue Green"></Color>
```

Is there any way to make sure that the elements in the list are unique?  For instance, is there any way to prevent Red from being in this list twice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the only way is using `xsd:pattern`. You want:

```
<xs:simpleType name="ColorEnum">
 <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
   <xs:pattern value="(Red){0,1}\s(Blue){0,1}\s(Green){0,1}"/>
 </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

This should enforce also the order. I mean you can't provide the sequence "Blue Green Red". Anyway it should be a starting point.

---

**EDIT** Very nasty:

```
<xs:simpleType name="ColorEnum">
 <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
   <xs:pattern value="((Red)?\s(Blue)?\s(Green)?)|((Red)?\s(Green)?\s(Blue)?)|((Green)?\s(Blue)?\s(Red)?)|((Green)?\s(Red)?\s(Blue)?)|((Blue)?\s(Green)?\s(Red)?)|((Blue)?\s(Red)?\s(Green)?)"/>
 </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

---

**EDIT**

The number of combinations is given by the factorial of the total number of elements you use in the sequence. I hope you won't exceed three elements then :)

Answer (score 1):

In XSD 1.1 (available now in Xerces and Saxon) you can do

```
<xs:assertion test="count(tokenize($value, '\s+')) = 
                    count(distinct-values(tokenize($value, '\s+')))"/>
```

Comment: +1 Nice to know. @webe0316: see http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-xml11pt2/

Answer (score 0):

I afraid that this is not possible with `xs:enumeration`, you can use some nasty regexp like:

```
  <xs:simpleType name="ColorEnum">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="(Red)?( Blue)?( Green)?"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

In this case the order of the elements is fixed.